# Unity and 2d applications

Tags: android, ios, 2d, unity-game-engine

I have on my mind to turn into Unity for future development but as for now I have a little knowledge about that engine. Therefore I would like to ask you if Unity is a good choice for development of 2d apps or is it good just for games? Does it provide same functionality like Android e.g. touch screen or iOS multi-touch?

Is it wise to use Unity for development of apps dedicated for Android and iOS or is it better to stick with those 2 separate paths of development for Android and iOS?

Comment: When you say "or development of 2d apps or is it good just for games" are you looking to use Unity to make 2D side scrollers or do you want to make non-game apps?  For non-game apps, do not use Unity.

Comment: To be more clear I meant a 2d drag and drop game. Is there a specific reason why Unity can't be used for non-game apps?

Comment: Unity is a game engine first w/ very limited support for user interface elements.  If you want to make a 2D drag n' drop game, Unity will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you! It is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very possible to create a good 2D game in Unity. In fact, following with your comment:

> To be more clear I meant a 2d drag and drop game. Is there a specific
>   reason why Unity can't be used for non-game apps?

It is perfectly fine for Unity to create non-game apps, even in 2D. The good thing about Unity is that you can EASILY create utilities/software/non-game apps. Unity makes a great software platform in general for multiple platforms. For the most part, Unity has the power of C# Mono for logic and features.

One of the pitfalls of using Unity is the GUI. For getting a good GUI, you may want to look at some alternate third-party Unity plugins.

In other words, Unity is great for all-around multi platform development. :)